# Javascript Return More Than One Range From Array.from() Method

Tags: javascript, arrays, selenium, selenium-ide

Very new to Javascript, as I'm primarily using it to execute commands in Selenium IDE. I've been using the range function provided by Mozilla's documentation for the array.from() method. This is how I put it together in Selenium:

```js
const range = (start,stop,step) =>
  Array.from(
    { length: (stop - start) / step + 1},
    (_, i) => start + (i * step)
  );
  return(range(179,199,1))
```

Is there a way to return more than one range? Why doesn't this work? (In Selenium IDE, it completely skips over this command.) Is it because it's a multi-dimensional array?

```js
const range = (start,stop,step) =>
  Array.from(
    { length: (stop - start) / step + 1},
    (_, i) => start + (i * step)
  );
  return (range(179,199,1), range(201,210,1))
```

Comment: I seems you use an arrow function without braces, and then use return and think that the return expression is associated with the arrow function, which in fact is not true.

Comment: The other problem you have, is trying to run both the return functions wrapped in parentheses, which evaluates the first value, does nothing with it and then evaluates the second value - the one you return. If you wrap both `range` expressions in square brackets `[]` brackets you'll see everything works

Answer (score 2):

you used a `()` where you have to use either object `{}` or array `[]` to get multiple ranges as below

```js
const range = (start, stop, step) => Array.from({
  length: (stop - start) / step + 1
}, (_, i) => start + (i * step));
var a = () => ([range(179, 199, 1), range(201, 210, 1)])
var b = () => ({"range1":range(179, 199, 1),"range2": range(201, 210, 1)})
console.log(a());
console.log(b());
```

Comment: This works outside of Selenium, but for some reason doesn't seem compatible with the IDE.

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: This is Selenium's IDE (which is probably not what you think when you think IDE). It's basically a GUI that provides record and playback to test web features.